# A deadlock exception when the H2-database is used with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

This is question from [github issue of H2](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3611)

Optimistic locks of H2 has deadlock exception when the isolation>2 in Hibernate.

I don't understand.

Could you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is expected. When you use an isolation level like SERIALIZABLE, the database will abort certain transactions that can not be serialized. You will just have to implement a retry mechanism.